# How to merge a list containing data and datetime64[ns] with a pandas dataframe with datetime64[ns] index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime64

I want to read two columns S1_max and S2_max from a `dataframe` `data`. Wherever a value is present in the S1_max column I want to check that each `S1_max` is succeeded by a corresponding `S2_max` signal. If so I calculate the time delta between the `S1_max` and `S2_max` signal. This result is then indexed at the `datetime[64ns]` index of the S2_max column in a separate `dict` `d`which is then appended to a `list` `delta_data` . How can I add this result to my already existing `data` dataframe at the corresponding `datetime[64ns]` index?

This is my creation of `delta_data`:

```
#time between each S2 global maxima: 86 ns/samp freq 200 = 0.43 ns
#Checking that each S1 is succeeded by a corresponging S2 signal and calculating the time delta:
delta_data = []
diff_S1 = 0
diff_S2 = 0
i = 0
while((i + diff_S1 + 1 < len(peak_indexes_S1)) and (i + diff_S2<len(peak_indexes_S2))):
# Find next ppg peak after S1 peak
    while (df["S2"].index[peak_indexes_S2[i + diff_S2]] < df["S1"].index[peak_indexes_S1[i+diff_S1]]):
        diff_S2=diff_S2+1

    while (df["S1"].index[peak_indexes_S1[i+diff_S1+1]] < df["S2"].index[peak_indexes_S2[i + diff_S2]]):
        diff_S1=diff_S1+1

    i_peak_S2 = peak_indexes_S2[i + diff_S2]
    i_peak_S1 = peak_indexes_S1[i + diff_S1]

    d={}
    d["td"] = (df["S2"].index[i_peak_S2]-df["S1"].index[i_peak_S1]).microseconds
    d["time"] = df["S2"].index[i_peak_S2]
    PATdata.append(d)

    i = i + 1

time_delta=pd.DataFrame(delta_data)
```

`delta_data` printed out:

```
         td                    time
0    355000 2019-08-07 13:06:31.010
1    355000 2019-08-07 13:06:31.850
2    355000 2019-08-07 13:06:32.695
```

This is my `data` dataframe:

```
                           l1        l2        l3        l4       S1       S2   S2_max   S1_max

2019-08-07 13:11:21.485  0.572720  0.353433  0.701320  1.418840  4.939690  2.858326  2.858326       NaN
2019-08-07 13:11:21.490  0.572807  0.353526  0.701593  1.419052  4.939804  2.854604       NaN  4.939804
```

This dataframe is created by:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
data.columns = ['l1','l2','l3','l4','S1','S2']
nbrMeasurments = sum(1 for line in open('file.txt'))
data.index = pd.date_range('2019-08-07 13:06:30'), periods=nbrMeasurments-1, freq="5L")
```

I have tried `DataFrame.combine_first`and `append`.

Also, the same problem occurs when trying to add another dataframe to `data`. This dataframe doesn't have ms in the datetime frame:

```
                     S3   S4 
Date                                       
2019-08-07 13:06:30         111          61
```

Comment: please try to be more precise (and less verbose) when asking a question. For instance in your question you mention "datetime[64ns]" but it does not appear in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand you are trying to append another column to an existing DataFrame.

here how to do it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['bla', 'blah', 'blahh'], 'values':[1,2,3]})
df2_to_concat = pd.DataFrame({'put_me_as_a_new_column':['row1', 'row2', 'row3']})

pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2_to_concat.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

The `reset_index(drop=True)` makes sure you don't produce NaNs or duplicate index columns.

Comment: how do I make this work when my "PATdata" and "data" dataframes are different (I have added the PATdata so you can see). Sorry for my imprecision, but since I'm uncertain about the question, I'm having difficulties filtering out vital and trivial information (thus making the question verbose).